# Question marks in place of unicode(Hindi ) characters in JPA query in Spring?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am using hindi characters in where clause in JPA query. When I print the queries in console using show jpa the chars are being replaced by `????`.

I have used

```
value="${jdbc.url};databaseName=${jdbc.databaseName};useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=UTF-8"
```

In jdbc url but its not solving the problem.

Following the console output.

> Hibernate: select facilitysc0_.blockId as col_0_0_, formxpaths1_.xPath as col_1_0_, formxpaths1_.label as col_2_0_, formxpaths1_.formXpathScoreId as col_3_0_, case when ?='all' then case when formxpaths1_.xPath not in  (? , ? , ? , ?) then CONVERT(float, count(case when facilitysc0_.score='???' then 1 end))/CONVERT(float, count(case when facilitysc0_.score='???' or facilitysc0_.score='????' or facilitysc0_.score='???? ????' or facilitysc0_.score='' then 1 end))*100 else CONVERT(FLOAT, count(case when facilitysc0_.score='???' then 1 end))/CONVERT(FLOAT, count(case when facilitysc0_.score='???' or facilitysc0_.score='????' then 1 end))*100 end else CONVERT(FLOAT, count(case when facilitysc0_.score='???' then 1 end))/CONVERT(FLOAT, count(case when facilitysc0_.score='???' or facilitysc0_.score='????' then 1 end))*100 end as col_4_0_, case when ?='all' then count(case when facilitysc0_.score='???' or facilitysc0_.score='????' or facilitysc0_.score='???? ????' or facilitysc0_.score='' then 1 end) else count(case when facilitysc0_.score='???' or facilitysc0_.score='????' then 1 end) end as col_5_0_, count(case when facilitysc0_.score='???' then 1 end) as col_6_0_ from FacilityScore facilitysc0_ inner join FormXpathScoreMapping formxpaths1_ on facilitysc0_.formXpathScoreId=formxpaths1_.formXpathScoreId inner join LastVisitData lastvisitd2_ on facilitysc0_.lastVisitDataId=lastvisitd2_.LastVisitDataId where formxpaths1_.formId=? and (formxpaths1_.type like 'select_one yes_no%') and ((facilitysc0_.score in (? , ?)) and (formxpaths1_.xPath in (? , ? , ? , ?)) or (facilitysc0_.score in (? , ? , ? , ?)) and (formxpaths1_.xPath not in  (? , ? , ? , ?)) and ?='all' or facilitysc0_.score in (? , ?)) and (lastvisitd2_.DateOfVisit between ? and ?) and lastvisitd2_.IsLive=1 group by facilitysc0_.blockId , formxpaths1_.xPath , formxpaths1_.label , formxpaths1_.formXpathScoreId

Please help.

Comment: Hard to guess whether it is a mere display problem or a conversion problem: what is your system, how is the console configured, etc... Without more context, you question is *unclear*.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Hi, I am using Eclipse Neon on Windows 7.Console configuration is default.

Comment: The characters being weird in the console isn't really a biggie - have you tried outputting them on an actual page?

Comment: @EvanKnowles Yes you were right..I changed the console settings and could see the characters but still they are not being properly inserted in query..I looked up and found that we have to place N before unicode chars..but Jpa is throwing error of undefined N  found..How can i solve this?

Comment: query parameters will always be displayed as ? in console. What is the actual error or issue with the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change your JDBC URL to

`value="${jdbc.url};databaseName=${jdbc.databaseName};useUnicode=yes;characterEncoding=UTF-8"`

Note the useUnicode=*yes*

Answer (score 1):

Use the following connectionProperties for enabling unicode

```
useUnicode=yes;
characterEncodinng=UTF-8
```

by default the parameter values are hidden and to check the values that are being binded, logging is to be enabled with the the log4j.properties

```
# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n


# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

# Hibernate logging options (INFO only shows startup messages)
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO

# Log JDBC bind parameter runtime arguments
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=trace
```

or import **p6spy** jar and update the spy.properties with corresponding jdbc driver and log file location.